# Riemann integration of given function

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

Let $f$ be a function on $[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=x^2$ if $x$ is rational  and $f(x)=x^3$ if $x$ is irrational. Does it follows that $$\frac{1}{4}=\int_{\underline 0}^{1} fdx  < \int_{0}^{\bar 1} fdx =\frac{1}{3}$$
(So far I have figured out that the function is not Riemann Integrable hence Upper integral should be strictly greater than the lower integral)  .

Comment: It'd probably be clearer to underline/overline the whole integral, say $$\underline{\int_0^1}f\,dx$$ and etc.

Comment: @Joanpemo yes,But I am new here and still trying to figure out how to change it.

Comment: The rational numbers have measure $0$, so the integral in the Lesbesgue-sense is $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: @Peter True , but I am checking the Riemann integrability here.

Comment: You should define what the "lower" and what the "upper" integral is here. Do you mean the integrations over $x^2$ and $x^3$ ? In this case, you are obviously right.

Comment: @Peter What the measure of the rationals in the unit interval has to do here? If the points of non-continuity were only the rationals then I agree the function would be integrable, but it is not the case, in my opinion. The function isn't continuous *anywhere*, and at the extreme points we only have one-sided continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be some partition and $[t_{i-1}, t_{i}]$ be a subinterval. There are rationals arbitrarily close to ${t_i}$, and, since $x \mapsto x^2$ is continuous and increasing, the $\sup$ of the image of $g:\mathbb{Q} \cap [t_{i-1}, t_{i}] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x) = x^2$  is $(t_i)^2$.   On the other hand, if we consider irrationals, the $\sup$ is $(t_i)^3 \leq (t_i)^2$. It's quite clear then that the upper sums for a given partition are the same as the upper sums of $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x^2$ and so the upper integral (ie $\frac 13$) is the same as well.

You can use a similar argument for the lower integral to get $\frac 14$ as the value. Then conclude that the function is not Riemann integrable.